# How to make nautilus' FTP connections stay live for longer times?

Tags: nautilus, ftp, gvfs

I use Nautilus FTP connections (I think it's gvfs) for all FTP transfers I do and since I do many per day, I'd like to have them all kept alive, but they disconnect after like a minute.

I think some FTP clients can keep connections alive by sending NOOP every X seconds. Can I somehow make Nautilus do the same?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/410288 :)

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as off topic however, in case someone comes here having the same problem, this answer on Super User solved it for me: http://superuser.com/a/605433/219676